# redux state is not recognized after npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, redux, production

#### npm run build not working with redux and state

When running npm run build it generates a new folder "build", I am using CRA, create-react-app, the problem is next:

I have a state which is comming from mapStateToProps, my state is called language, when I run **npm start** and make a console.log of "**this.props.language**" then it prints **null** and everything is working as expected, then I have a condition:

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1eKX.png)

```
{this.props.language
                ? this.props.language.result.map((language, index) => (
                    <Link
                      key={index}
                      className="dropdown-item"
                      to={`/tutorials/${language.toLowerCase()}`}
                    >
                      {language}
                    </Link>
                  ))
                : null}
```

when I run "**npm run build**" and later "**serve -s build**", the "**this.props.language**" is **not null**, in fact is:
[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjI1Y.png)

Please, can anybody help me? I was searching in google, but could not find much information about it, thank you very much!

Comment: The first thing I am going to recommend is that you stop using `jsx` extensions, even the engineers of React recommend against it. Change all `jsx` extensions to `js`. Second, I have no idea what I am looking at here, so please post the code from your `App.js` for starters and any other relevant code that can help me help you.

Comment: It was a problem of my env, in the service I was calling relative url, /api/bla so, it was not working under production, it was calling the url of the react app instead of the url of the endpoint, and the react app was returning the react html code of course, that's why I was getting that html code from the action in redux, I notice it using redux __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ in chrome, I am practically new to react, I have never before deployed a react app, that is why I did not know about .env.development and .env.production, again, thanks very much for the othe suggestion!

Comment: Go ahead and post your resolution as the answer and be as precise as you were in the comments so that others may benefit.